# Width and Height values are automatically swapped after uploading to server. [PHP]

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, dimensions, getimagesize

I used this function [`getimagesize($file_tmp_name)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get width and height of the image I uploaded.
The function returned a 2D array: `$width = arr[0]` and `$height = arr[1]`;

[image]

On my PC, the image demension is: 3024 x 4032 (w x h)
But on the server side, the image width and height values are swapped. 4032 x 3024 (w x h)

```
 var_dump($width); // C:\wamp64\www\upload_script\Image.php:89:int 4032
 var_dump($height); // C:\wamp64\www\upload_script\Image.php:90:int 3024
```

I'm not sure what caused this and how can I make it consistent. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Exif data. Basically when you take picture on your phone image is always in  same orientation, since phone is aware of orientation, portrait and landscape, it will set exif data to image which says in which orientation to show image. When you open that image on your PC image preview program will read exif data and show image in correct orientation. You need to check now to read exif in PHP and rotate image if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check first comment on [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function in php manual.

Code copied from there:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']));
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }
}
// $image now contains a resource with the image oriented correctly
?>
```